# Install Poetry with Github Actions, poetry command not found. Cannot add Poetry into Path

Tags: python, github, github-actions, cicd, python-poetry

I'm learning the basics of Github Actions for CICD. I use Poetry for Dependencies Managements. But I keep throwing `poetry: command not found`. If I run `source $HOME/.poetry/env` in every step (which opens new shell with my limited knowledge), It works. I tried to modify the `.bashrc` with `cat $HOME/.poetry/env >> ~/.bashrc`, but It doesn't work.

Here is my Yaml file, thanks ^^

```
name: Django CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      # - develop
      - master

jobs:
  Unit tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy: # Strategy
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.8]
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Github repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
          source $HOME/.poetry/env
          cat $HOME/.poetry/env >> ~/.bashrc
          poetry install
          echo "OK"
      - name: Run unit tests
        run: |
          # If I run "source $HOME/.poetry/env", It works
          poetry run python manage.py test
```

Answer (score 3):

You better use [this action](https://github.com/snok/install-poetry) to install Poetry and setup the venv.

Here is what I use in my projects. It includes caching of the complete venv. The cache is invalidated by a different Python version and/or a modification in `poetry.lock`.

```yaml
    - name: Install and configure Poetry
      uses: snok/install-poetry@v1
      with:
        version: 1.1.13
        virtualenvs-create: true
        virtualenvs-in-project: true
    - name: Set up cache
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: cached-poetry-dependencies
      with:
        path: .venv
        key: venv-${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.full-python-version.outputs.version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: poetry install
      if: steps.cached-poetry-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that, from [this thread](https://github.community/t/self-hosted-not-using-bashrc/18358):

> Github Actions invoke bash scripts in non-interactive mode, it will not load `.bashrc` by default.

Only [`/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` would be sourced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499/7490) (you have some [other alternatives](https://superuser.com/a/1341348/141)).

Or you need to source it explicitly:

```
source $HOME/.poetry/env
```

Comment: So with every step, I need to source it, again and again, @VonC

Comment: @KhaiHoanPham Yes, that can be the issue indeed.